# Microsoft SQL server - cannot start Enterprise Manager

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2000

I have a windows 2000 system, running Microsoft SQL server 2000, and a lot of other junk.

When I try to start the Enterprise Manager, I get the following error message.

> Snap-in failed to initialize:
>   Name: Microsft SQL enterprise Manager
>   CLSID: {00100100-1816-11D)-8EF5-00AA0062C58F}

In my searches, I have come across 2 knowledge base articles that seem to match the issue, but they don't help.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/826282/en-gb : The PATH already includes the C:\WINNT\system32\Wbem directory.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914157 : I don't think anyone has ever installed "Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Backward Compatibility Components", and the registry entry is correct, and I have re-registered the sqlmmc.dll file

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Enterprise Manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you login to SQL from SQL query analyzer? or cmd -> isql? 
I mean is the SQL engine functioning, just that you can't open the Enterprise Management console?

It could a problem on client tools and re-installing them can fix it.

Comment: Re-installing Enterprise manager, as specified in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa197918(v=sql.80).aspx appears to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

What user are you logged in with?

You don't think .. or you know nobody installed any extras? all the solutions i have googled mention installing sql2005 on the same server..

[try this link](http://sqlserver-qa.net/blogs/tools/archive/2008/01/08/snap-in-failed-to-initialize-name-microsoft-sql-enterprise-manager-clsid-00100100-1816-11d0-8ef5-00aa0062c58f.aspx)

Comment: I'm logged into the system as our network administrator, which works perfectly for our other (supposedly identical) server.It's unlikely that anyone has installed any sql2005 stuff on this machine, as there would be no reason to, though I wouldn't swear to to.

Comment: There's an easy way to find out if anyone installed any other SQL components... Go to Add/Remove Programs and look.

Comment: There was nothing in Add/Remove that looked the slightest bit like 2005 had been installed.